# Add custom message in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to add a custom message once someone saves a specific content-type telling them that it is going through an approval process. This will let them know as well as prevent them from re-submitting.

Comment: What do you mean with 're-submitting'? If you're afraid that simply refreshing the page will submit the form again, don't worry, Drupal has taken care of that.

Comment: not refreshing. more like the user thinks it hasn't gone through the first time they tried so they fill out the form again and submit. that's what i meant by re-submitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is a small custom module that does something like this (completely untested):

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($node->type == 'custom_node_type' && $op == 'insert') {
    drupal_set_message(t('Put your custom message here.'));
  }
}
```

For more info, see the docs for [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi) and [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_message/6)

*Edited to reflect the below comments.*

Comment: Actually this is a better route but I would change 

if ($op == 'insert') to if ($node['type'] == 'custom_node_type' && $op == 'insert')

Comment: ...and if your message needs to be translated in different languages, wrap it in the t() function: drupal_set_message(t('Put your custom message here.'));

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do without a custom module.

One way I would try and do this is to overwrite the [post-submit URL](http://drupal.org/node/134000).

Then in the new page, use a PHP filter and do the following:

```
drupal_set_message('The submitted content is being approved');
drupal_goto('');
```